# undefined reference to function declared in header and implemented in cpp file

Tags: c++, function, linker-errors, header-files

I'm working on some basic C++ code that uses two cpp files(Main.cpp and CarbStore.cpp) and one header(CarbStore.h). Within my header I have declared a function that is later implemented in CarbStore.cpp. When I call the function from my Main.cpp it gives me the error:

> Main.cpp:17: undefined reference to `CarbStore::CalcCarbs(unsigned char, unsigned char, unsigned char, float, unsigned int, std::__cxx11::basic_string, std::allocator >) const'

My files contain the following code:

> Main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdint>
#include <cmath>
#include <ctime>

#include "CarbStore.h"


void CarbCalculator()
{
    CarbStore carb;
    carb.CalcCarbs(10, 11, 12, 0.1, 100, "test");
}

int main(int,char *[])
{
    CarbCalculator();

    std::cout << "Press enter to exit." << std::endl;
    std::cin.get();
}
```

> CarbStore.cpp

```
#include "CarbStore.h"
#include <iostream>

void CalcCarbs(unsigned char r, unsigned char b, unsigned char g, float bounciness, unsigned int price, std::string manufacturer)
{
    //use values at later state
    return;
}
```

> CarbStore.h

```
#ifndef CARBSTORE_H
#define CARBSTORE_H
#include <vector>

class CarbStore
{
public:
    void CalcCarbs(unsigned char r, unsigned char b, unsigned char g, float bounciness, unsigned int price, std::string manufacturer) const;
};



#endif
```

Comment: Your definition of `CalcCarbs` is a non-member function. Use `void CarbStore::CalcCarbs() { ... }` to make it a member function.

Comment: You wrote a ::CalcCarbs() function, it is not an implementation of the CalcCarbs class constructor.  Write CalcCarbs::CalCarbs(...) to get ahead.

Comment: They are both being compiled together in my makefile, hence my confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As already told in the comments, the following

```
void CalcCarbs(unsigned char r, unsigned char b, unsigned char g, float bounciness, unsigned int price, std::string manufacturer)
{
    //use values at later state
    return;
}
```

does not implement the member function `CalcCarbs` of `CarbStore`, but instead it declares and defines a new free function called `CalcCarbs`. To implement the member function you need to tell the compiler to which class the function definition should belong. This is done by appending the class name together with a double colon before the function name:

```
void CarbStore::CalcCarbs(unsigned char r, unsigned char b, unsigned char g, float bounciness, unsigned int price, std::string manufacturer)
{
    //use values at later state
    return;
}
```

The signature must also match. In `CarbStore` you declared the function `const`, but you did not do so in the implementation. To correct it:

```
void CarbStore::CalcCarbs(unsigned char r, unsigned char b, unsigned char g, float bounciness, unsigned int price, std::string manufacturer) const
{
    //use values at later state
    return;
}
```

However it is highly unlikely that you really want a `const` member function with empty return, because such a function can only have a lasting effect by modifying global variables or doing IO.

Furthermore, but unrelated to this particular error message:

1. In `CarbStore` you are using a `std::string`, so you need to `#include<string>`. On the other hand I don't see any `std::vector` in it, so the `#include<vector>` seems unnecessary (as do all the other includes besides `iostream` in `Main.cpp`).
2. The `return;` at the end of the function body is also point-less for a `void` function.
3. If `main` doesn't use the command line arguments, you can also give it the signature `int main()`.